# Does google offer any way to silently refresh/keep alive an access token gained from implicit flow?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, access-token

I am being forced to use implicit flow for a windows application as it cannot safely store the `client_secret` and while Google says they support PKCE Code Authorisation flow, it REQUIRES you have the `client_secret` sent over, which seems a bit silly to me, but due to this I am forced to use the implicit flow to get an `access_token`.

So with that out of the way I can get the `access_token` fine, but unlike some other OAuth providers there seems to be no way to silently refresh or replace the `access_token`. For example when using Twitch they provide a `validate` endpoint which essentially seems to tell Twitch to keep your access_token alive for a while longer. So I am trying to find a way to achieve something similar, as the application ideally wants the user to login once and then not have to re-login after an hour or between app restarts etc.

If this were using PKCE I would have a `refresh_token` which solves all these concerns but in implicit flow I seem to have no way to silently keep the users `access_token` alive and must force them to log back in every hour/time they open the application.

So is there any way to achieve this? or do I have to wait for google to support secretless PKCE then do it the proper way with `refresh_tokens`.

For additional context the application in question is open source (another reason why `client_secrets` cant be put in, ignoring decompilation concerns), it is C# based and spins up a tiny webserver in process for handling the callbacks etc from google/other OAuth providers (and some other bits).

Comment: google does not support sliding access tokens.   If you must use implicit flow then your going to have to have the user login again.  Refresh tokens only work in server side applications.  Not client side JavaScript using implicit flow

Comment: This isn't client side JS its a native windows app so technically it does have a server side component but its not secure as anyone could decompile it and see the secret. I thought this would be the case though, so really there is no avenue here until they properly support PKCE for native apps, but this has been requested for years and they dont seem to be doing anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

It feels like your issues derive from connecting clients to Google identity provider (IDP) endpoints directly. When integrating with an IDP it is common to then run into problems due to lack of control over tokens.

**WORKAROUND**

As a short term fix you might solve your immediate issue by running a code flow in the desktop app, then routing requests requiring a client secret via an API, which could attach it.

**AUTHORIZATION SERVER ROLE**

You are likely to find that connecting to the Google IDP via your own authorization server (AS) provides the best control. The AS could then provide the client secret to Google.

Your own AS should give you control over flows according to OAuth and OIDC standards. Running a code flow should enable you to use many authentication methods and factors. Client code should not need to know which authentication method is used.

The AS should enable you to design access tokens for your own clients and APIs, with custom scopes, claims and lifetimes. This can include issuing a custom claim containing the Google access token if needed. Note that identity provider access tokens are not intended to be used by your own APIs.

**SUMMARY**

I would always put the client and API requirements first. Use the standard code flow for your native client. But also think through your token requirements. Understand the difference between an AS, which gives you control over tokens for your own APIs, and an IDP, which does not.

Comment: The app in question connects to plenty of other IDPs such as Twitch, Twitter, Discord etc and none of them have these issues. The problem imo seems to be with google as their implementation of PKCE code authorisation seems to deviate from the standard, as the client secret should be un-needed. Either way though there is no scope for creating a separate closed source API (my own Auth server) or using a 3rd party paid for service to act as a go between (i.e Okta).

Comment: Makes sense - many IDPs are not quite standards based and have their nuances, as you are finding. The options are either to deal with them in your application code or by using an AS.